# How to create a view from Bigquery REST api

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a view in Bigquery from REST api.
Please let me know if possible.
please share some sample code.

thanks,

Chandan Reddy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a view by calling tables.insert with a table resource containing a "view" property.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

Answer (score 5):

The following code works .. !!

```
     Table content= new Table();    
     TableReference tableReference= new TableReference();
     tableReference.setTableId("ViewName");
     tableReference.setDatasetId("DataSetName");
     tableReference.setProjectId(getProjectId());
     content.setTableReference(tableReference);

    ViewDefinition view= new ViewDefinition();
    view.setQuery("SELECT * FROM [DataSetName.TableName]");
    content.setView(view);
    System.out.println(content);
    bigquery.tables().insert(getProjectId(), "DataSetName", content).execute();
```

Comment: [DataSetName.TableName] <- The datasetname was missing for me!

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, that's not possible at the moment.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views

The supported ways of creating a view are the command line tool and the web interface. You can programatically invoke the command line tool and then use the table "patch" method via REST to update the query used for the view if necessary.

Comment: Can you share some sample code to update a view by using patch()

Comment: It is possible to create a view using tables.insert. Sorry about the confusing documentation--we'll see if we can fix it.